# Azure pipeline fails on building Kotlin Multiplatform shared framework usinig embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode and fastlane

Tags: xcode, kotlin, azure-devops, fastlane, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm working on a Kotlin Multiplatform project which is building fine locally but I can't get it to work on an Azure DevOps pipeline.

Some good things to know:

- not using Cocoapods
- using the `embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode` gradlew command in Build Phases
- all commands using `fastlane` work for multiple developers locally
- we use custom configurations like: ProjectADebug/ProjectARelease but we defined `KOTLIN_FRAMEWORK_BUILD_TYPE` for all of them

I'm trying to get an Azure DevOps pipeline to build and upload to App Store Connect using `fastlane`. We are using `match` for signing, that works great. Archiving fails and it looks like it's failing on building the shared KMM framework.

Anybody with the same problems that could help me out? Or some tips how I can view those `gym` logs on the Azure VM because I assume there it says what actually went wrong instead of this general error.

```
▸ Running script 'Build Kotlin Common'
▸ Copying /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-ffubndppzitzbxhibjgeavrhnzpw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Project/BuildProductsPath/ProjectRelease-iphoneos/Airship_AirshipCore.bundle
▸ Copying /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-ffubndppzitzbxhibjgeavrhnzpw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Project/BuildProductsPath/Project Release-iphoneos/Airship_AirshipAutomation.bundle
** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution Build\ Kotlin\ Common /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-ffubndppzitzbxhibjgeavrhnzpw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Project/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Project.build/ProjectRelease-iphoneos/Project.build/Script-2F4970EC27CD16A000E32F91.sh (in target 'Project' from project 'Project')
(1 failure)
ERROR [2022-05-10 13:04:32.36]: Exit status: 65

ERROR [2022-05-10 13:04:32.53]: ⬆️  Check out the few lines of raw `xcodebuild` output above for potential hints on how to solve this error
WARN [2022-05-10 13:04:32.53]:   For the complete and more detailed error log, check the full log at:
WARN [2022-05-10 13:04:32.53]:   /Users/runner/Library/Logs/gym/Project-Project.log
```

This is the the lane in Fastfile:

```
    lane :azure_beta do |options|

        label = options[:label].capitalize

        git_url = "someURL"

        match(
            type: "appstore",
            readonly: true,
            git_url: git_url,
            keychain_name: ENV["MATCH_KEYCHAIN_NAME"],
            keychain_password: ENV["MATCH_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD"],
            verbose: true
        )
        
        build_app(
            project: "../Project/Project.xcodeproj",
            configuration: "#{label}Release",
            scheme: label
        )
        # fails on the build_app step...
        
        changelog = changelog_from_git_commits(
            pretty: "- (%ae) %s",
            date_format: "short",
            merge_commit_filtering: "exclude_merges"
        )

        upload_to_testflight(
            changelog: changelog,
            app_identifier: label == "Project" ? idsProjectA : idsProjectB,
            skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true
        )

        version_number = get_version_number(
            xcodeproj: "../Project/Project.xcodeproj",
            target: "Project", #Hardcoded because we have multiple targets, label is specificed in build_app configuration
            configuration: "#{label}Release"
        )

        add_git_tag(
            includes_lane: false,
            prefix: "ios-#{label.downcase}-#{version_number}-",
            build_number: number_of_commits
        )

        delete_keychain(name: ENV["MATCH_KEYCHAIN_NAME"])
    end
```

And this is my pipeline YAML:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-latest'

variables:
- group: fastlane

jobs: 
- job: testflight
  steps:
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: fastlane update
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        gem update fastlane
        fastlane --version
  - task: JavaToolInstaller@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '11'
      jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
      jdkSourceOption: 'PreInstalled'
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: 'Update Dependencies'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew bundle
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: "Set build properties"
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        echo "sdk.dir=/Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk"
        echo "INCLUDE_MOCKER=false" >> local.properties
        echo "INCLUDE_ANDROID=false" >> local.properties
        echo "INCLUDE_TESTER=false" >> local.properties
        echo "APP_LABEL=$(APP_LABEL)" >> local.properties
    env:
      APP_LABEL: $(APP_LABEL)
  - task: Gradle@2
    displayName: 'Clean label common'
    inputs:
      workingDirectory: ''
      tasks: "common:cleanLabel"
    env:
      APP_LABEL: $(APP_LABEL)
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: fastlane ios
    env:
      MATCH_PASSWORD: $(MATCH_PASSWORD)
      FASTLANE_PASSWORD: $(FASTLANE_PASSWORD)
      FASTLANE_SESSION: $(FASTLANE_SESSION)
      FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD: $(FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD)
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode_13.2.app
        cd ios/Project
        fastlane azure_beta label:Project app_identifier:project.bundle.id itc_team_id:itc.team.id team_id:team.id git_match_branch:master username:me@myself.com
```

Comment: have you tried opening `/Users/runner/Library/Logs/gym/Project-Project.log`? You need to see full log for the script execution error

Comment: @PylypDukhov how can I open that log on the Azure VM? Is there a script that can print the output or something?

Comment: try [connecting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/ssh-from-windows) via ssh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out there was an error in building the common KMM layer, I would have found it when doing a clean checkout probably but I found out by using a self-hosted agent on Azure Devops so I could navigate to the `/Users/runner/Library/Logs/gym/Project-Project.log` as Pylyp Dukhov suggested.